# Replace number and email with XXXX in a sentence using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'd like to replace the numbers and email from the sentences.

**Example**

$message = "Hi this is john, my personal no is 1213456789 and my email address is john@gmail.com".

*Output:*

> Hi this is john, my personal no is 1213456789 and my email address is john@gmail.com

I want the Output to be like this:

*Output:*

> Hi this is john, my personal no is XXXXXXX789 and my email address is XXXX@gmail.com

*But I'm currently getting like this :*

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com

function which I'm using now

```
function numbers1($str)
{
 if(($until = strpos($str, '@')) !== false)
 {
  $str = str_repeat('X', $until) . substr($str, $until);
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: first how do you make the string `$message` ? are the mobile and email are dynamic generated?

Comment: @sgt <?php echo numbers1($email['message']); ?>

Comment: If you do this for securing the information, it is really not safe to do it on the client.

Comment: are those no. & email static? why do you want to use jquery?

Comment: I'm not prefering jQuery. In my previous result I used jQuery. If anyone can get solution in someother. It's ok for me. I need the solution that's it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message = "Hi this is john, my personal no is 1213456789 and my email address is john@gmail.com";
$arr = explode(" ", $message);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{   
    if(!preg_match ("/[^0-9]/", $val))
    {
        $val_new = "XXXXXXX".substr($val, -3);
        $arr[$key] = $val_new;
    }
    else if(strpos($val, "@")>0)
    {   
        $arr_email = explode("@", $val);
        $arr_email[0] = "XXXX";
        $val_new = implode("@", $arr_email);
        $arr[$key] = $val_new;
    }
}

$new_msg = implode(" ", $arr);
echo $new_msg;
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
$message = "Hi this is john, my personal no is 1213456789 and my email address is john@gmail.com";
    $arr = explode(" ", $message);
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {   
        if(!preg_match ("/[^0-9]/", $val))
        {
            $val_new = "XXXXXXX".substr($val, -3);
            $arr[$key] = $val_new;
        }
        else if(preg_match ("/^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$/", $val))
        {   
            $arr_email = explode("@", $val);
            $arr_email[0] = "XXXX";
            $val_new = implode("@", $arr_email);
            $arr[$key] = $val_new;
        }
    }

    $new_msg = implode(" ", $arr);
    echo $new_msg;
```

Comment: Thank you SKRocks. You are really rocking. You have relieved me from headache. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm facing bugs in this code. Ex : If the email address is like this `abc@gmail.com` then it showing the result as `XXX@gail.com`. But if the email address is like this `abc @gmail.com` then the result is like this `abc @gmail.com` ** . _jQuery is not validating the **space**_ I mean no changes in the output**. Please fix this issue and post back soon.

Comment: in above code you can put the validation of email in second if condition. ok i am posting it with update

Comment: the above will convert xxx only for valid email address

Comment: Okay. What I wanna do now.?

Comment: because `abc @gmail.com` is not a valid email id

Comment: Actually I'm creating a dating site. So, In that the users should not share his/her contact no and email address. If I apply this code, then they can share the information easily with having spaces before **@**. What wanna do now.? Give some suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

try  `preg_replace()`

```
$str = "Hi this is john, my personal no is 1213456789 and my email address is john@gmail.com";
$replacements[1] = 'X';
$replacements[0] = 'XXXX@';
echo preg_replace(array('/[0-6]/', '/[ a-z]{0,4}+@/'), $replacements, $str);
```

output :- `Hi this is john, my personal no is XXXXXXX789 and my email address is XXXX@gmail.com`

Comment: This won't work with a phone number such as `723456789`, you would end up with something like `7XXXXX789`. It's completely harcoded.

Comment: @cafonso Yes. You are correct. It's having some little bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to do this using jQuery, however your sample code is written in PHP. I'll answer your question with a PHP snippet as well.

The reason why your function isn't working is because you're replacing pretty much everything from the beginning of the string up to the position where the first '@' is found. Then you're adding as many 'X' as characters are until that position, followed by the rest of the string. To complicate things more, this won't work if two or more email addresses are found in your string.

This should do. You might need to tweak the regexes for both the phone numbers and the email addresses, though:

```
$message = "Hi this is john, my personal no is 1213456789 and my email address is john@gmail.com";

// get all phone numbers
preg_match('/\d{3,}/s', $message, $phones);
// get all email addresses
preg_match('/[a-z.-]+@[a-z.-]+/s', $message, $emails);

foreach ($phones as $phone)
{
    $message = str_replace($phone, str_repeat('X', strlen($phone) - 3) . substr($phone, -3), $message);
}

foreach ($emails as $email)
{
    $parts = explode('@', $email);
    $message = str_replace($email, str_repeat('X', strlen($parts[0])) . '@' . $parts[1], $message);
}

// Hi this is john, my personal no is XXXXXXX789 and my email address is XXXX@gmail.com
echo $message;
```